# Archivos CSV y agregar datos

Tags: python, csv

Hola gente tengo una duda. Se supone que los archivos csv se separar por comas y en une nueva linea cada uno se si agrega el método a. La cosa es que en mi documento no se agregan al final sino que a la par. este es mi código

```
archivo = open("plantilla.csv","a")
# el usuario agrega la informacion que le pido para que luego se guarde en otro documento
#despues de eso los quier agregar a ese archivo csv, asi que hice lo siguiente
archivo.write(dia)
archivo.write(",")
archivo.write(mes)
archivo.write(",")
archivo.write(año)
archivo.write(",")

archivo.write(nombre)
archivo.write(",")
archivo.write(peso)
archivo.write(",")
archivo.write(estatura)
archivo.write(",")

archivo.write(hora_inicio)
archivo.write(",")
archivo.write(hora_finalizacion)
archivo.write(",")
archivo.write(tiempo_sesion_para_archivo)
archivo.write(",")
archivo.write("\n")

archivo.close()
```

sin embargo el resultado me queda diferente como

```
Dia,Mes,Anio,Nombre,Peso,Estatura,Hora Inicio,Hora Final,Tiempo Sesion25,04,2021,pablo,149,165,17.34,19.38,2.04,
```

en vez de que se haya un espacio entre cada linea, no tengo idea de que estoy haciendo mal. Se supone que me deberia de quedar asi...

```
Dia,Mes,Anio,Nombre,Peso,Estatura,Hora Inicio,Hora Final,Tiempo Sesion
25,04,2021,pablo,149,165,17.34,19.38,2.04,
```

ayuda!

Comment: Abres el fichero en modo "a", por lo que lo que tú estás escribiendo se añade a lo que ya había. Se ve que en lo que ya había faltaba un `\n` al final de la primera línea, la que tiene los nombres de los campos.

Comment: Por cierto que yo simplificaría todos esos `write` en uno solo: `archivo.write(",".join([dia, mes, año, nombre, peso, estatura, hora_inicio, hora_finalizacion, tiempo_sesion_para_archivo])+"\n")`

Comment: `...se separan por comas...` Si bien CSV significa *comma separated values*, el separador puede ser casi cualquier cosa, incluso términos compuestos. Pero si, lo usual son las comas.

Answer (score 0):

```
archivo = open("plantilla.csv","a")
archivo.write("\n")

archivo.write(dia)
archivo.write(",")
archivo.write(mes)
archivo.write(",")
archivo.write(año)
archivo.write(",")

archivo.write(nombre)
archivo.write(",")
archivo.write(peso)
archivo.write(",")
archivo.write(estatura)
archivo.write(",")

archivo.write(hora_inicio)
archivo.write(",")
archivo.write(hora_finalizacion)
archivo.write(",")
archivo.write(tiempo_sesion_para_archivo)
archivo.write(",")
archivo.write("\n")

archivo.close()
```

Está muy bien tu código. Te faltaba añadir un salto de línea para que aparezcan en dos lineas diferentes los resultados: `archivo.write("\n")`

El resultado es:

```
Dia,Mes,Anio,Nombre,Peso,Estatura,Hora Inicio,Hora Final,Tiempo Sesion
25,04,2021,pablo,149,165,17.34,19.38,2.04,
```

Además, puedes simplificar el código usando `archivo.write(",".join([dia, mes, año, nombre, peso, estatura, hora_inicio, hora_finalizacion, tiempo_sesion_para_archivo])+"\n")`, que une las variables indicadas con una coma como separador de los valores.